# Why is there an error that occurs randomly saying Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, css-selectors

I creating an expense tracker app, and I have the user's expense record stored in a table by date, title, amount, and an empty column for an 'x' button to delete that row's expense document. When the user clicks the 'x' button it deletes the document from firestore and removes its data from the row.

Occasionally, when the 'x' button is clicked the document is deleted from firestore but doesn't remove itself from the table unless the page is refreshed which is basically reading the expense documents over again since the document was deleted from firestore.

```
app.js:189 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '[data-id=6yl9aPRGzLn1FCbXecfI]' is not a valid selector.
```

```
/* CURRENT MONTH'S EXPENSE TABLE  */
const table = document.querySelector('#record');

function expenseRecord(user) {
  const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection(`${year}-${month}`).orderBy('date', 'desc').limit(20);

  docRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach((change) => {
      if (change.type == 'added') {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        let date = document.createElement('td');
        let title = document.createElement('td');
        let amount = document.createElement('td');
        let cross = document.createElement('td');

        tr.setAttribute('data-id', change.doc.id);
        cross.setAttribute('class', 'btnDelete');
        date.textContent = change.doc.data().date;
        title.textContent = change.doc.data().title;
        amount.textContent = `$${change.doc.data().amount}`;
        cross.textContent = 'x';

        tr.appendChild(date);
        tr.appendChild(title);
        tr.appendChild(amount);
        tr.appendChild(cross);

        table.appendChild(tr);
        cross.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
          db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection(`${year}-${month}`).doc(id).delete();
        });
      } else if (change.type == 'removed') {
        let li = table.querySelector('[data-id=' + change.doc.id + ']');
        table.removeChild(li);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```
<table id="record">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is line 189

```
let li = table.querySelector('[data-id=' + change.doc.id + ']');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, document IDs generated by Firestore can contain letters and numbers. When an ID starts with a number, this causes the attribute selector to fail because without quotes around the attribute value, the attribute value is treated as a CSS `<ident>` token, which cannot start with a number. This is why you only see the selector failing occasionally.

Adding quotes around the attribute value will ensure it isn't treated differently by the parser depending on the nature of the document ID:

```js
let li = table.querySelector('[data-id="' + change.doc.id + '"]');
```